# Mysql query get result by month and year

Tags: php, mysql

Table `inventory_month` has three fields `id` , `month_month`  and `month_year`

```
id month_month month_year
1  09          2012
2  10          2012  
3  11          2012
4  01          2013
5  02          2013
6  03          2013
7  09          2013 
8  10          2013
```

I need result FROM October  2012 TO October  2013 as below

Expected result

```
id month_month month_year

2  10          2012  
3  11          2012
4  01          2013
5  02          2013
6  03          2013
7  09          2013 
8  10          2013
```

But getting result below

Getting result

```
id month_month month_year

2  10          2012 
8  10          2013
```

I have tried query below

`select id,month_month,month_year where month_month>=10 AND month_year>=2012 AND month_month<=10 AND month_year<=2013`

Need helpful suggestion, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use,

```
SELECT id,month_month,month_year WHERE
(month_month >= 10 AND month_year = 2012)
OR     
(month_month <= 10 AND month_year = 2013)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your condition logic is incorrect.

You need to replace your 2nd `AND` statement to an `OR` statement and add brackets.

```
(month_month>=10 AND month_year>=2012) OR (month_month<=10 AND month_year<=2013).
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it include September 2012 also , means getting all  records

Comment: You need bit more editing to get OP's expected one. @user3218154 - Try my one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select id,month_month,month_year where (month_month>=10 AND month_year>=2012)
Or (month_month<=10 AND month_year<=2013)
```